# Unaligned memory access with AC flag does not raise any trap on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, alignment, sigbus, eflags

With Intel x86_64 CPU.
I am trying to catch "unaligned memory access fault" on Windows.
this works perfectly on Linux (Ubuntu).

For example, I can turn on the AC flag on EFLAGS register like this

```
    pushfd
    or DWORD PTR[esp], 0x40000
    popfd
```

Then, misaligned memory access (e.g., DWORD read/write on 0x804a003) raises SIGBUS error for Linux process.

However, with same CPU, if I do the same thing on Windows (7 and 8), nothing happens.  can someone explain me why??  is this because Windows disables the CR0.AM flag and Linux does not?

I would appreciate some advises.
thank you.

Comment: Why do you conclude that it doesn't trap on Windows? AFAICT, the CPU traps and Windows ignores the trap. Note that `SIGBUS` isn't the trap itself, but what Linux generates in response to a trap.